# Using basic authentication in SAP PI calls from .NET

Tags: wcf, basic-authentication, sap-pi, sap-xi

I'm getting the error message below when trying to call the SAP PI Web Services using C#.net console app:

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="XISOAPApps"'.m="XISOAPApps"'.
```

My custombinding looks like this:

```
<customBinding>  
        <binding name="CustomHttpTransportBinding">  
          <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"  
              messageVersion="Soap11" writeEncoding="utf-8">  
            <readerQuotas maxDepth="10000000" maxStringContentLength="10000000"  
                maxArrayLength="67108864" maxBytesPerRead="65536" maxNameTableCharCount="100000" />  
          </textMessageEncoding>  
          <httpTransport authenticationScheme="Basic" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"  
              hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" keepAliveEnabled="false"  
              proxyAuthenticationScheme="Basic" realm="XISOAPApps" useDefaultWebProxy="true" />  
        </binding>  
      </customBinding>
```

Could anyone please correct me if I'm doing something wrong above?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you add the user name and password for the system on the proxy?

Comment: Yep, proxy.Credentials.Username="anyuser"; proxy.Credentials.Password="good".

Comment: I'd suggest using message logging on the client or fiddler to see what your request looks like on the wire and see if anything looks out of place

Answer (score 9):

SAP PI webservice with Basic Authentication:

```
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding ...>
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
```

Comment: Thanks John, unforetunately, svcutil still outputs the same warning even with the updated namespace.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that your SAP web service credentials are correct, and not locked. I just came across this error, and I asked my SAP P.I. Admin to verify the SAP service credentials, and it turns out that they were locked. Everything worked fine once she unlocked the SAP credentials for me.